# Local minima of composite function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, partial-derivative

I have a function $f(u(x), v(x))$ where $u(x)=g_1(x)$, $v(x) = g_2(x)$. so basically both function determined on same input $x$. I wonder is there a way to proof $f$ can reach (local) optima when $u(x) = a$, where $a$ is a constant value?

the difficulty here is $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ is not independent, suppose there's no way to extract exact $x$ from $u(x) = a$, is there exist a rigorous way to prove this hypothesis?

Comment: Can you explllcitly show the function(s)? Otherwise it's not obvious to me that anyone understands what you're talking about.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, thanks for the feedback, unfortunately the $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$ are black box functions so I cannot show their closed form, for $f(u(x), v(x))$ there has a closed form, for example it can be $f(u(x), v(x)) = (u(x)-a)^2 + v(x)^2$. I just wanna keep the problem general as if there're some common approach to solve this problem, is that help?

Comment: Then your whole problem is essentially black box, so you need to use an oprtmization method suitable for black box functions.